Error when evaluating SSR module F:\oceanh_workspace\Project\blog-astro\astro.config.mjs: failed to import "astro-icon"
I have an astro website and starting today when I build locally 'astro dev/build' will report the following error.
OS: Windows10
Node version: v20.16.0
Package manager: Pnpm v9.7.0
Astro version: v4.13.1
Error Message:
[vite] Error when evaluating SSR module F:\oceanh_workspace\Project\blog-astro\astro.config.mjs: failed to import "astro-icon"
|-file:///F:/oceanh_workspace/Project/blogastro/node_modules/.pnpm/@iconify+tools@3.0.7/node_modules/@iconify/tools/lib/svg/index.mjs:1
import cheerio from 'cheerio';
^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'cheerio' does not provide an export named 'default'
at ModuleJob.instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:134:21)
at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:217:5)
at async nodeImport (file:///F:/oceanh_workspace/Project/blog-astro/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.4.0@types+node@22.2.0_lightningcss@1.25.1_sass@1.77.8_stylus@0.63.0_terser@5.31.5/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-NjL7WTE1.js:52928:15)
at async ssrImport (file:///F:/oceanh_workspace/Project/blog-astro/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.4.0_@types+node@22.2.0_lightningcss@1.25.1_sass@1.77.8_stylus@0.63.0_terser@5.31.5/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-NjL7WTE1.js:52786:16)
at async eval (F:/oceanh_workspace/Project/blog-astro/astro.config.mjs:10:31)
at async instantiateModule (file:///F:/oceanh_workspace/Project/blog-astro/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.4.0_@types+node@22.2.0_lightningcss@1.25.1_sass@1.77.8_stylus@0.63.0_terser@5.31.5/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-NjL7WTE1.js:52844:5)
[astro] Unable to load your Astro config
The requested module 'cheerio' does not provide an export named 'default'
Stack trace:
at ModuleJob.instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:134:21)
at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:316:24)
at async ssrImport (file:///F:/oceanh_workspace/Project/blog-astro/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.4.0@types+node@22.2.0_lightningcss@1.25.1_sass@1.77.8_stylus@0.63.0_terser@5.31.5/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-NjL7WTE1.js:52786:16)
at async instantiateModule (file:///F:/oceanh_workspace/Project/blog-astro/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.4.0_@types+node@22.2.0_lightningcss@1.25.1_sass@1.77.8_stylus@0.63.0_terser@5.31.5/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-NjL7WTE1.js:52844:5)
ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
I've tried a lot of ways, like removing node_modules, clearing pnpm's cache, updating dependent versions, and even rolling back the code to previous versions, but nothing has fixed the problem, which drives me crazy.Plz help me.

This problem is solved in @iconify/tools version 4.
import cheerio from 'cheerio'; → import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';
If you are using astro-icon, this issue will also be helpful: https://github.com/natemoo-re/astro-icon/issues/231
